# Bind socket to a free port from non-ephemeral port range

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

It is common knowledge that in order to bind a socket fd to a random free port, you pass `0` as `sockaddr_in.sin_port` to the `bind`. However, this seems to always assign a port from ephemeral port range, as illustrated by the below program [*].

My question is, is there a [clean] way to get a random port from **non-ephemeral** port range?

[*]

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  fstream ports("/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range", fstream::in);
  int eMin, eMax; ports >> eMin >> eMax;
  cout << "ephemeral range: [" << eMin << ", " << eMax << "]" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    bind(fd, (sockaddr*)(&addr), addrlen);
    getsockname(fd, (sockaddr*)(&addr), &addrlen);
    uint16_t port = ntohs(addr.sin_port);
    bool within = (port >= eMin) && (port <= eMax);
    cout << "port " << port << " " << (within ? "in" : "out") << endl;
    close(fd);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

P.S. Right now the workaround I'm using is to explicitly pass a random port number from non-ephemeral port range as `sockaddr_in.sin_port`, try to bind to it, rinse-repeat if bind operation failed. But this feels like emulating something the system should provide.

Comment: I don't know if there's a general way, but on for example linux you can tell what ports are in use from the /proc/net pseudo files, and so presumably pick an unused one with a little less blind trial and error.

Comment: For what purpose? Why do you care what the value is? And if you do, why can't you use a fixed value?

Comment: I don't see any indication that this is possible, and that sort of makes sense, given that their definition of _ephemeral_ is, essentially, "numbers that nobody is going to care about and so can be handed out without thinking."

Comment: Cannot reproduce it... which OS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

> Right now the workaround I'm using is to explicitly pass a random port number from non-ephemeral port range as `sockaddr_in.sin_port`, try to bind to it, rinse-repeat if bind operation failed. But this feels like emulating something the system should provide.

Sadly, that is exactly what you need to do.  There is no standard or platform-specific API for selecting an available random port from a range of *non-ephemeral* ports.  The OS only knows about *ephemeral* ports, as that range is part of its networking configuration.

Answer (score -2):

Source port allocation in typical TCP/IP stack is not particularly sophisticated. At least BSD TCP/IP stack is fairly straightforward. If you explicitly bind to particular port number, then the stack either allows it or it does not. If you don't bind to particular address, the stack allocates one from ephemeral port range. At least in BSD stack automatic port allocation always happens from the ephemeral port range. I suspect TCP/IP stack behaves very similarly in Linux as that's standard bind() behavior.

Comment: How does this answer the question asked?

Comment: The answer is that there is no "[clean] way to get a random port from non-ephemeral port range" in a BSD TCP/IP stack where "clean" == "provided by the stack". Obviously proving that there's no clean way in all implementations of TCP/IP would be rather hard.

Comment: @ArtemB: it would not be hard if networking stacks provided an option, say a custom opcode of `setsockopt()`, to set a user-defined range of ports on a per-socket basis that `bind()` could then search through instead of the OS's default ephemeral range.  Oh well, we can only dream...

Answer (score -2):

My answer assumes that non-ephemeral in your question refers to the privileged port range 1-1024. In case you mean some other range, adjust the numbers in the commands accordingly.

On Linux you can do this quite "cleanly", but with it will take effect for *all* local applications. I do realise that strictly speaking this just makes this new range the ephemeral port range...

```
awk '{print $2}' /etc/services |awk -F"/" '{if ($1 && $1 < 1025) print $1}'|tr '\n' ', '|sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_reserved_ports > /dev/null
echo "1 1024"|sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range >/dev/null
```

The first line adds privileged ports that might be in use to a list of ports that are not used in the selection. The second line sets the range for the local port selection to 1-1024.

In case you want it to be application specific, I can not help you. Perhaps it might be possible with network namespaces and a dedicated interface for that application, but I do not know how exactly.

Comment: This finds a free port in a range but doesn't bind a socket to it, and when you come to bind to it you may find that the  port had been taken in the meantime. Timing-window problem. Not a practical solution, and not an improvement over what the OP is already doing, whyever he's doing it.

Comment: @EJP you are a real sweetheart and make life in these tags so very bright.